# How to search a file in Freya?

Tags: release-freya, search

I have no clues to search and get file through the file manager. Any idea how to search file in it, Also sometimes I need to search a list of files with certain extension. we can do it like this in windows "*.txt" .But how about Freya. can we do it like this  ?

here is my window screenshot, where can I get search option here in it[image]

1. I need to search in directory and its sub directory, it should get all the names in the any depth sub folders.
2. Also I want to search with file extensions like if i type "*.txt " it should get all the files ends with same extensions.

Comment: particular directory and overall too. Where i can type and search it. No idea for me now

Comment: "Where"? Well, go to the directory, start typing. It will show available files/folders list on top. :)

Comment: with this the "*.txt" is not possible .

Comment: alright, i will wait for any other possible solutions to simplify the search.

Comment: Oops, my bad, its a duplicate.

Comment: its my bad. I have not find it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly search for `file/folder` in current directory by typing name of the file you want.

If you want any specific tool for thispurpose: use `gnome-search-tool`

To install open terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-search-tool
```

Now open and search.

[image: Imgur]

You can modify search using `select more options`

For your second requirement: Here `data` is my **partition**, the search listed all files ends with `.mp3` in folders/sub-folders.

[image: Imgur]

Comment: ofcourse, this is fine one for me, let me try use possible searches

Comment: testing now. without getting right solution i dont accept asnwers

Comment: how could  you get this search window

Comment: Go to applications menu --> you will see app

Comment: Actually this is not like what i expected. Somehow its not easier User interface.